# How to make J-Query ui dialog, modal using jquery ui 1.8.17

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog

My code is as follows :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('<div id="dialogDiv">' + 'This is a dialog.' + '</div>').appendTo('body');
            $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
            });
            $('#btnLoad').click(function () {
                $('#dialogDiv').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLoad" Text="Load" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want my dialog to be modal so that I can not click on "Load" button again till my dialog is closed. But with my above code i can still click on "Load" button.

I am using JQuery ui 1.8.17. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? Also there are scroll bars appearing even though my content is just a sentence. how do I hide only horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after reading documentation of J-Query-UI. The solution is that we need to modify below class as per our need :

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background: #aaaaaa ;/*important line to know that the class is in effect*/
            opacity: .3;
            filter: Alpha(Opacity=30) /*{opacityOverlay}*/;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just tested your code with jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 and it worked perfectly. Perhaps this didn't work as desired with the older versions?

Comment: What can be solution for older versions? Also which browser did you check this code in?

Comment: I checked in Chrome. As for a solution for older versions, I'm not sure off-hand, honestly. Is there a specific reason why you can't use a newer version?

Comment: yes... The resource is in centralized server and since it is being used in other projects I can't ask to change version. Also I tried in  Version 28.0.1500.71 of chrome and IE 10 but it did not work... Though it works in FireFox v22. Is there any specific reason its not working in IE. I need to develop code as per IE standards. Can you please help me?\

Comment: If I add "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" as css, My purpose is served. Can you please tell me which code of styles I am looking for in this file?